# Get a hidden div using AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to get some records using AJAX. I generate two div elements for every record like below

```
<span id="abc" class="hiden" style="visibility:hidden; display:none;">record here</span>
<tr id="123"><td>Record here</td></tr>
```

This is fetched data via Jquery AJAX. But after I get this data using AJAX, a span whose property is hidden shows in output, meaning span is not hidden and both spans are displaying. I want to show only `tr` when data fetch and hide span.

How can i do it?.
Please help me

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. You say you generate two divs. Do you mean two elements? I don't see any `div`'s in your code. `<tr>` belongs inside a table, and `<span>` can not be placed in between `<table>` and `<tr>`. Your question needs some more information to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anyone try to put a `span` and a `tr` as sibling elements, in my life.

I am assuming this is inside of a `table` element, right?

If so, take the `span` out of there, and see what happens.

Also, you don't need `visibility:hidden;` when you have `display:none;` it's sort of pointless, and redundant.